# extract and replace (YouTube ONLY) Iframe src

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube

If a YouTube iframe html is

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The jquery should test the iframe `src` to see if the first 29 characters match `http://www.youtube.com/embed/`

if it does apply a jquery to extract the `VIDEOID` after `/embed/` and replace the iframe src with `http://www.redirect.mysite.com/?id=VIDEOID`

so the iframe's src below

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EhrYQrLBiTQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

should be replace with

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.redirect.mysite.com/?id=EhrYQrLBiTQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/cRFgv/

Code:

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace('http://www.youtube.com/embed/', 
                                         'http://www.redirect.mysite.com/?id=');
});
```

Comment: Not what i was looking for exactly but only very little configuration

Comment: `$('iframe').each(function(){
    this.src = this.src.replace('http://www.youtube.com/embed/', 
                                              'http://www.redirect.mysite.com/?id=');
});`

Comment: @Yusaf it should all be up to snuf now :-D